# Cannot read property from undefined - Google Script

Tags: javascript

I have issues with this code, I can't make JSON splitting part correctly. I constantly get the following error: *TypeError: Cannot read property "cu_id" from undefined.*

part of JSON data looks like this (it is too big to show all, but the rest is the same)

```
{"started":"2022-01-15T12:56:08.197","finished":"2022-01-15T12:56:08.207","action":"RECEIVE","status":"SUCCESS","username":"sciarlo","subject":"340382659301954864","object":"10834376","result":"Created lots 5265995","trace_id":"LC3tS16A","properties":{"arrival_id":"ARR-98fc5b2b-cad2-4033-9bff-3af5cd779946","cu_id":"10834376","cu_quantity":"62","freshness_date_format":"NONE","load_carrier_barcode":"340389301954864","location":"3403826554864","purchase_orders":"366469","receive_type":"SSCC","temperature_zone":"AMBIENT","tu_id":"10834376","tu_quantity":"62"}}
```

Here is the part of code with issues:

```
  var receiveActions = []
  var latestTimestamp = receiveTab.getRange(2, 19).getValue();
  var actionTime = new Date(outputArray[0].finished)
  receiveTab.getRange(3, 19).setValue(actionTime);

  for (var i in outputArray) {
    var receiveAction = outputArray[i];
    if (new Date(receiveAction.finished) > new Date(latestTimestamp)) {
      
      var article = receiveAction.properties.cu_id;
      var location = receiveAction.properties.location;
      var temperatureZone = receiveAction.properties.temperature_zone;
      var cuQuantity = receiveAction.properties.cu_quantity;
      var tuQuantity = receiveAction.properties.tu_quantity;
      var tuSize = cuQuantity/tuQuantity;
      var timestamp = new Date(receiveAction.finished);
      var user = receiveAction.username;
      
      receiveActions.push([timestamp,user,temperatureZone,article,location,tuQuantity,tuSize])
    }
  }
```

Thank you in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid, it begins with a bracket/array but doesn't end with a bracket/array.

This makes me feel that you have more than one object entry in your JSON, and that the one you're showing us isn't the problem.

Are you sure that all of your objects in the JSON structure contains the  **receiveAction.properties** element?

Comment: 1. Yes, it is correct full JSON is quite large. therefore I only send a part. 2. Yes, all of them contains such structure.

Comment: One more example: {"started":"2022-01-15T12:56:08.197","finished":"2022-01-15T12:56:08.207","action":"RECEIVE","status":"SUCCESS","username":"sciarlo","subject":"340382659301954864","object":"10834376","result":"Created lots 5265995","trace_id":"LC3tS16A","properties":{"arrival_id":"ARR-98fc5b2b-cad2-4033-9bff-3af5cd779946","cu_id":"10834376","cu_quantity":"62","freshness_date_format":"NONE","load_carrier_barcode":"340389301954864","location":"3403826554864","purchase_orders":"366469","receive_type":"SSCC","temperature_zone":"AMBIENT","tu_id":"10834376","tu_quantity":"62"}}